# Would a semi colon be appropriate in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semicolons

We previously ordered Flood insurance coverage for you to cover our interest in the property above; however, this coverage has been canceled. Please review the enclosed Evidence of Cancellation effective as of the date indicated above.

Would this be correct usage? Please explain why or why not. I read up quite a bit on the independent clause situation, but I just want to make sure I am making sense of this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon is fine in this example. A semicolon is used to connect two related independent clauses without using a comma or a conjunction. Both portions of the sentence are independent clauses, no conjunction is used, and the sentences are closely related, so a semicolon would work here.